# Winrt c# copy image from asset to localstorage

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, copy, local-storage

I come to you today because i don't know how to copy an image from asset to localstorage. I try a something like :

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("appx:///Assets/image.png"));

await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "image.png");
```

But it doesn't work at all. Does anyone have an idea to do this right ?
Thanks for your time,
Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Uri scheme is invalid. It should be `ms-appx:`, not `appx:`:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.png"));

await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "image.png");
```

See this post for valid Uri schemes: [URI schemes supported in Windows 8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020014/uri-schemes-supported-in-windows-8-apps)

Comment: Yeah what i wrote before is working with the full uri, sorry for this dumb question. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link

[Download an image to local storage in Metro style apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836367/download-an-image-to-local-storage-in-metro-style-apps)

Also

[How ro store image locally once it was downloaded by Image control in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441617/how-ro-store-image-locally-once-it-was-downloaded-by-image-control-in-windows-8)

Might be helpful.